How to pan GoogleMap composable inside ModalBottomSheet in JetPack Compose
I'm trying to put a GoogleMap() composable inside a ModalBottomSheet() in JetPack Compose. Here is a very simplified version of the code:
        ModalBottomSheet(onDismissRequest = {  }) {
            GoogleMap() {}
        }

My problem is that dragging on the map drags the ModalBottomSheet instead of panning the GoogleMap.
How do I get the GoogleMap to pan with user touch?
Click below to see the current behavior:
https://imgur.com/a/fsrflt8

If you are using the Compose Material3 version of ModalBottomSheet(), try passing false for the sheetGesturesEnabled parameter.

Thank you. My problem is that sheetGestureEnabled is only an arguemtn in material3.jvmstubs. So I have trouble using it while having the rest of my composables that are from material3.android.
Have you come across this before?

@ArashGobal: No, but I do not use Compose Material3. That function is documented as being part of the common sourceset, not the JVM one in a Compose Multiplatform project.
